# Javascript: Find left and right word of certain keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

For statistical purposes, I need to find out **related keywords**.

So, I want to fetch the word just before and just after the searched word. And then count the fetched words and show them as top related keywords based on no of times, they are on left or right of searched keyword.

e.g. If I search 'google', and I have 3 sentences.

1. Facebook is still behind Google.
2. Google sucks
3. Twitter is behind google too.

Then , it should fetch 'behind', 'sucks' and 'too'. Now, they should be placed as top related keywords like,

**Top related keywords:**

1. behind   2
2. sucks    1
3. too      1

I do not want to include certain keywords in top related keywords like 'to', 'from' , 'by' etc. i.e Ignore them if they are on left and right side of searched keyword.

What I have done so far,

```
// Searched keyword is 'future'.


// Created an array of sentences
var data = [
{para : 'hi, how are you . Good luck for lovely future.'},
{para : 'Future is in your hands'},
{para: 'The power of future'},
{para: 'The life is a mystery'},
{para: 'The power of future'},
{para: 'Join the future'},
{para: 'Google+ is future facebook'},
{para: 'I pray for your good future'}
];

// created a hash of words to be avoided
var avoid = {
'to': true,
'from': true,
'in' : true,
'for' : true,
'by': true,
'since': true,
'the': true
}

for(k in data){
   var text = data[k].para;
   /* Here I need to find the words on left and right of future,
      but they should not include 'to', 'from', 'in', 'for', 'by', 'since'*/
}
```

It should fetch.

**Top Keywords:**

1. is        2
2. of        2
3. lovely    1
4. facebook  1
5. good     1

Can somebody help me or give some idea how to find left and right words ? or How should I do this ? The 'so far' approach is right or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//I made your `avoid` variable into an array so I can use `.join()` on it
var avoid = [
'to',
'from',
'in',
'for',
'by',
'since'
];

//make the regular expression that will look for each of the words, globally and case-insensitive
var avoidReg = new RegExp(avoid.join('|'), "gi");

//this type of loop is much faster than `for (k in data)`
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {

    //get the text for this index, replace the `avoid` words and split the string at spaces
    //you can then get the first and last indexes of the array
    var text = data[i].para.replace(avoidReg, '').split(' '),
        first = text[0],
        last  = text[(text.length - 1)];
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VrUxc/

Here is a JSPerf to show the performance increase of the `for` loop I used: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

This isn't a perfect solution but it's a starting point. For instance if the first or last word is an `avoid` word then you will get a space as that word.

### Update

If you want to search for a word and get the words before and after it you can use `.indexOf()` to find the index of the word:

```
var avoidReg = new RegExp(avoid.join('|'), "gi"),
    search   = 'future';

for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var text   = data[i].para.toLowerCase().replace(avoidReg, '').split(' '),
        index  = text.indexOf(search),
        before = text[(index - 1)],
        after  = text[(index + 1)];
    
    if (typeof before == 'undefined') {
        before = 'N/A';
    }
    if (typeof after == 'undefined') {
        after = 'N/A';
    }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VrUxc/2/

Comment: Its actually calculating first and last word of sentence.

I want to fetch word just before and just after the searched word 'future'.

Comment: Btw for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {} is a very nice tip for beginners like me :)

Comment: :) That was tricky, I can work on this from now on. Thanks , thanks a lot for giving a perfect direction :)

Your comments on your code helped me alot :)